# Who is Gakuhō Asano wife? What is their story?

Tags: assassination-classroom

The anime features him only having a son but how did that come to happen? Him being a superhuman and all, he probably wouldn't settle down for a normal girl, or would he? What is the story there? Did he ever get married?

Comment: i bet it was Nagisa's Mom :v or maybe his "Son" is in fact his Clone :v

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from reading the wikia for the show, they have no mentioned the mother yet.

This is less of an answer and more of a "there is no answer" type thing.

Although I'm all for the idea of him having cloned himself into his son. That opens some very frightening possibilities and some interesting conclusions. Does he have more clones? If his son-clone turned out like that, then could the father actually be a good person that was changed by bad circumstances? I'd watch that.

Comment: What are the indicators of his son being his clone?

Spoiler: Watch the latest episode to see how the father was good then bad.

Comment: @demirb 

SPOILERS: It gives a background of the father, but it doesn't mention anything regarding his family. The father did change a lot, but we don't have enough information regarding his son. The son doesn't match either the young or the old versions of his father, so it's difficult to say if they have more than a normal family bond that drives the other similarities. I'm like my father, but I'm not his clone. Unless I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the principal got married, had a son, and went kind of crazy for power. Power seems to be way too important for him. Maybe his wife left because of that.